# Can't access directory in PATH

Tags: windows, system-variable

When I do `echo %path%` I see system32 in there. I try to use setx and it can't find it. I issue a command to add system32 to the path and now it sees it. If I close the cmd window and reopen I have to do this all over. so, programs trying to kick off cmd files that access things in system32 don't have the set path command in it fail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: there shouldn't really be any spaces around the `;` in the path. try removing them  and see if that helps any. and to set env vars permanently/globally, you'd have to go through the system control panel's advanced options.

Comment: it was the spaces, thanks a lot!